# Why "Display:none" is property not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a dropdown mega menu for the navbar that would have the menu expanded on a large device and minimalized on a small device. I will provide photos with what I done so far and what I want to achieve,

I tried to hide the div with display none, position absolute and move it -9999px away and with `.remove()` on JS, but nothing worked so far.

```js
if (window.innerWidth <= 986)
  $('.lateral').addClass("hide");
else
  $('.lateral').removeClass("hide");
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 986)
    $('.lateral').addClass("hide");
  else
    $('.lateral').removeClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.lateral {
  position: relative;
  width: 98%;
  height: 28%;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

.hide {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lateral">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav mr-auto vertical-menu">
      <li class="navbar-header">
      </li>
      <li id="NavDropdown" class="navbar-collapse collapse vertical-menu
    ">
        <p>produs</p>
      </li>
      <li id="NavDropdown" class="navbar-collapse collapse vertical-menu ">
        <p>produs</p>
      </li>
  </div>
  </ul>
  </nav>
```

I expected my code to delete the whole div, not just the text from it.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. This is the source of your problem. You should delete this, fix your errors, and then re-ask the question if you still have issues. Note that `display:none` will not "delete" anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do no think the issue is with `display: none`.

There's a few issues on the code:

1. The HTML tree is corrupted as some elements are closed before their children are.
2. The CSS code should be within a `<style></style>` tag.
3. The JavaScript is missing curly braces. In theory, it should work, but the code is more error prone if you do not add them.

```js
// Adjusted to 600 for better display in demo.
const changeSize = 600; 
if($(window).width() <= changeSize) {
  $('.lateral').addClass("hide");
} else {
  $('.lateral').removeClass("hide");
  $(window).resize(() => {
    if ($(window).width() <= changeSize) {
      $('.lateral').addClass("hide");
    } else {
      $('.lateral').removeClass("hide");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.lateral{
      position:relative;
      width:98%;
      height:28%;
      float:left;
      color: red;
    }
    
    .hide {
       display: none !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="lateral">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav mr-auto vertical-menu">
      <li class="navbar-header">Menu</li>
      <li id="NavDropdown" class="navbar-collapse collapse vertical-menu"><p>produs</p></li>
      <li id="NavDropdown" class="navbar-collapse collapse vertical-menu "><p>produs</p></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</div>

<div>
Content
</div>
```